# Delegate definitions - in/outside method makes any difference?

Tags: c#, delegates, mono

As tagged, I'm working with Mono, not .NET, if it matters.

I am confused about best practice for scope, when using delegates.  Note that in this example, *autoOrientations* and *autoRotationSetups* will be used elsewhere in the class, outside of *Awake()*.  Also note that when using [Unity](http://unity3d.com/), you often [use *Awake()* where you might otherwise be using a constructor](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/index.Writing_Scripts_in_Csharp_26_Boo.html):

```
List<ScreenOrientation> autoOrientations;
Dictionary<ScreenOrientation, Action> autoRotationSetups;

void Awake() {
    var verticalOrientations = new List<ScreenOrientation>(
        new []{ScreenOrientation.Portrait, ScreenOrientation.PortraitUpsideDown});  
    Action setAutoRotationsToVertical = () => {
        // I don't think this defintion is important for this question,
        // but it does use the just-defined List.
    };
    var horizontalOrientations = new List<ScreenOrientation>(
        new []{ScreenOrientation.LandscapeLeft, ScreenOrientation.LandscapeRight});
    Action setAutoRotationsToHorizontal = () => {// See last comment.
    };
    autoRotationSetups = new Dictionary<ScreenOrientation, Action>() {
        {ScreenOrientation.Portrait, setAutoRotationsToVertical},
        {ScreenOrientation.PortraitUpsideDown, setAutoRotationsToVertical},
        {ScreenOrientation.LandscapeLeft, setAutoRotationsToHorizontal},
        {ScreenOrientation.LandscapeRight, setAutoRotationsToHorizontal},
    }; //...
```

Alternatively, I could define class methods, and then assign them to delegates.  That alteration would look like:

```
List<ScreenOrientation> verticalOrientations, horizontalOrientations;
void SetAutoRotationsToVertical() {}
void SetAutoRotationsToHorizontal() {}

void Awake() {
    Action setAutoRotationsToVertical = SetAutoRotationsToVertical;
    Action setAutoRotationsToHorizontal = SetAutoRotationsToHorizontal; //...
```

Is there anything different happening under the hood, between these two approaches?  At my current knowledge level, I'm mostly concerned about variables living in the wrong area of memory; [The Truth About Value Types](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/09/30/the-truth-about-value-types.aspx) may clear that up, and I think I'm in the clear, but I don't understand it well enough yet to be totally confident.  Also, I'm not aware of any other possible reasons for going one way or the other, hence this question.

I have been getting questions closed lately because people thought they were subjective, so, although I value your opinion, "No." would be an acceptable answer.  "Yes" will likely require further explaining that's not purely stylistic choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there anything different happening under the hood, between these two approaches?

When you create the anonymous method via the lambda expression, the compiler just creates a method for you.  Realistically, the two versions will likely have very little difference.

The main difference is that, by allowing the compiler to create the anonymous method, you do open up the ability to use closures around locally defined variables within your `Awake()` method.  This might be a good thing, or a bad thing, depending on what you want - as it does potentially cause extra classes to be generated to hold the variables.

> At my current knowledge level, I'm mostly concerned about variables living in the wrong area of memory

I wouldn't worry about this so much - it's not like there is a "right" and a "wrong" area of memory...

Comment: Thanks!  The mention of closures led me here, which helped me a lot:  http://diditwith.net/PermaLink,guid,235646ae-3476-4893-899d-105e4d48c25b.aspx

Comment: @Jessy Note that the first option doesn't mean you will necessarily get a closure - it'll only happen if you use variables defined outside of the anonymous method.  If you keep everything local (ie: it's the same as the "normal method"), the two will be effectively identical.